# why my variational autoencoder can't learn

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

I am using 187 data as train set, which has 68 features
and would like to extract 10 features then use PCA to plot in 2D

my original data is right skewed but the latent space becomes normal

even though the loss decreases well, the model doesn't seem to be learning

[model] variational autoencoder

layer 68 - 30 - 10 - 30 - 68, using leaky_relu as activation function and tanh in the final layer

added l1 regularization in loss function, and dropout in the encoder

```
class VAE(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(VAE, self).__init__()

    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(68, 30)
    self.fc21 = nn.Linear(30, 10)
    self.fc22 = nn.Linear(30, 10)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(10, 30)
    self.fc4 = nn.Linear(30, 68)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)

def encode(self, x):
    h1 = F.leaky_relu(self.fc1(x))
    h1 = self.dropout(h1)
    return self.fc21(h1), self.fc22(h1)

def reparameterize(self, mu, logvar):
    std = logvar.mul(0.5).exp_()
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        eps = torch.cuda.FloatTensor(std.size()).normal_()
    else:
        eps = torch.FloatTensor(std.size()).normal_()
    eps = Variable(eps)
    return eps.mul(std).add_(mu)

def decode(self, z):
    h3 = F.leaky_relu(self.fc3(z))

    return torch.tanh(self.fc4(h3)) # sigmoid -> relu

def forward(self, x):
    mu, logvar = self.encode(x.view(-1, 68))
    z = self.reparameterize(mu, logvar)
    return self.decode(z), z, mu, logvar


model = VAE().to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3) # this will help for L2 regularization

def loss_function(recon_x, x, mu, logvar):
loss = nn.MSELoss(reduction = 'sum')
BCE = loss(recon_x, x)
KLD = -0.5 * torch.sum(1 + logvar - mu.pow(2) - logvar.exp())

regularization_loss = 0 # l1 regularization
for param in model.parameters():
    regularization_loss += torch.sum(torch.abs(param))

return BCE + KLD + regularization_loss
```

I have no clue why this is not working

[this is the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hguNZ.png)

[this is the one I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC0hI.png) -- very random

Comment: Can you explain, along with plots (if applicable), what you had expected and what finally happened.

Comment: I expected the latent space to be right skewed as the original data was, however the latent space was normal
I tried using PCA only, and it was right skewed as i expected
the data is expected to be non linear in 2D space so I would like to use autoencoder but it is not working

Comment: I don't think that the latent space will necessarily reflect the data distribution. The learnt data distribution is given by P(z) * P(x|z) where P(z) is an assumed prior (commonly a normal) and P(x|z) is given by the decoder. I think that if you sample z from a unit normal, then set x = decoder(z), then these x samples would be right skewed as you expected.

Comment: If I set x = decoder(z) then isn't this the reconstructed data?
I am trying to extract the features by dimension reduction, so my goal is to get the latent space that preserves the original data feature the most

Comment: A trained VAE represents the data distribution. New data points from the same underlying distribution can be sampled using the process I outlined in the previous comment. In your case, you expect that the latent space has the same metric as the data space. This constraint is not enforced when you train a VAE. Hence, you can't really expect that points which were close in the data space are close together in the latent space as well.

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation. Now I understand why.
Thank you so much!!

Comment: No problem friend! You may be interested in Multi Dimensional Scaling. I first learnt about it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38_dTFaTMxk&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=JustinSolomon).